# Is there such a thing as high temp magnet wire?

Tags: temperature, wire

I understand that magnet wire is enamel coated, which can tolerate temperatures up to approximately 250 °C. Is there any other insulated wire that can be tightly wound into (1 inch diameter) coils which can tolerate temperatures up to 500-600 °C?

Comment: I just googled and came by ceramic coated magnet wire. 1000C. No price listed which means...$$$

Comment: I wonder if you can coat the wire in something like clay that will bake/cure at that temp? Or maybe you can build up an oxide layer using electrolysis?

Comment: Thanks DKNguyen, I didnt realize there was ceramic coated wire. I contacted a couple of vendors.